Rank of matrix $a_i \cdot b_j + a_j \cdot b_i$
Find the rank of the matrix $d_{ij} = a_i \cdot b_j + a_j \cdot b_i$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary vectors.
I noticed that
$C = a \cdot b^T = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1}       \\
    ...       \\
    a_n
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1}       & \dots & b_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1} \cdot b_{1}       & a_{1} \cdot b_{2} & \dots & a_{1} \cdot b_{n} \\
    \dots  \\
    a_{n} \cdot b_{1}       & a_{n} \cdot b_{2} & \dots & a_{n} \cdot b_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$
Then the desired matrix $D$ such that:
$$D = C + C^T = a \cdot b^T + b \cdot a^T$$
So, $$rank(D) \leq 2\cdot rank(C)$$
Also, $$rank(AB) \leq min(rank(A), rank(B))$$.
Here $A$ - a column, $B$ - a row. So, $rank(C) = 1$.
And it means that
$$rank(D) \leq 2$$
However, I do not understand whether it is possible to accurately understand here whether the rank of the desired matrix is 1 or 2 and what it depends on.

Are you missing some transposes above?

Are you saying that $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are arbitrary vectors, or are $a$ and $b$ arbitrary vectors with scalar entries $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$?

I mean the second: $a$ and $b$ - vectors, $a_1, ...., b_n$ - scalars

The rank can be 0, as well.

Since $rank(D) \leq 2$ you can use $2 \times 1$ vectors to build some intuition. It's pretty easy to find examples with rank zero and one so you just need to check the rank two case.

Let's assume that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, i.e. $a$ is not a scalar multiple of $b$. Let $v_3, v_4, \dots, v_n$ be a basis of $\{a, b\}^{\perp}$. Then in the basis $a, b, v_3, v_4, \dots, v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $D = ab^T + ba^T$ has matrix representation $$D = \text{diag}(\begin{pmatrix}b^T a & |b|^2 \\ |a|^2 & a^Tb \\ \end{pmatrix}, 0).$$
The determinant of the 2 by 2 matrix is $(a^Tb)^2 - |a|^2 |b|^2$, which is negative by Cauchy-Schwarz and the linear independence assumption. Hence $D$ has rank $2$ in this case.

Can you explain, why D has so specific representation in this basis?

@Disciple Sorry it was off by a transpose. To see why, compute $Da$, $Db$, $Dv_j$ and write them in terms of the basis.
